# How do I know whether my Azure role was shut down by runtime or manually?

Tags: azure, cloud

I've deployed an Azure service - once in a while I see in my logs that `OnStop()` is called, then after about 20 minutes `OnStart()` is called. I'd like to know why that's happening.

How can I know whether my role is restarted manually or by Azure runtime?

Comment: Could just be azure patching the "server" (or rather just replacing the whole instanc with a patched one which I guess would be easier to do).  Can you remote desktop into the machine afterwards and check the logs?

Comment: @alun: Maybe. I can try to, but that looks like too much of hand holding - I'd like to have a more convenient way.

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain what you mean by restarted manually?  Is that someone logging in via RDP and hitting reboot?

You only have a few options that can trigger a reboot:

1. Someone logged in via RDP and literally rebooted.  No way to track that one.  Turn off RDP if you are worried about that being a common scenario.  I am not sure OnStop would even be called here.
2. The fabric controller shuts down the instance to a.) patch the guest OS if allowed (specifying * as guest OS version) or b.) patch the root OS occasionally.  You can most likely track this from looking at the infrastructure logs.  Setup diagnostics to watch and transfer those logs.  I have not personally tried this, but it would be my best guess to tie it together.
3. Someone hit 'Reboot' from portal or API. There is a [List Operations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg715318.aspx) history API call that you can check that will tell you which LiveID or certificate called the Reboot instance API.

So, if you see a OnStop, there is not much you can do about #1 short of turning off RDP (and as I said, I am not sure it would even trigger a OnStop).  You can otherwise look to the infrastructure logs and List Operations API to see what initiated it.

Comment: I guess the fabric controller wanted to patch the instance.