# How to know why my VMs are rebooted

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

I have a cloud service on Azure with three instances. Just for debugging purposes, I would like to know the reason(s) why my instances are rebooted automatically by the Azure engine. Is it possible? In other words, is there a log of these automated processes?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You can only guess http://stackoverflow.com/q/7062054/57428 - the exact reason is not logged anywhere where you could access it.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kwill/archive/2012/09/19/role-instance-restarts-due-to-os-upgrades.aspx which discusses the most common reason for restarts.